# Text replace in html from a json of key value without loops

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a json

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "key":"{ClientName}",
         "value":"ABX"
      },
      {
         "key":"{PhoneNumber}",
         "value":"1234 578 988"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have a requirement where I want to replace a text on the webpage.
The pattern of the string is
"Please contact us at {PhoneNumber} and our client is {ClientName}"

I am trying to replace the variable with values in the given json.

Is there any jquery method to perform such task without a loop?

Thank you.

Comment: Is [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#what-is-handlebars) an option?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just not make a call like items["key"].ClientName and items["key"].PhoneNumber? If not, you can try converting your json list into a dictionary with key/value pairs, to access like the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
var line = {
            PhoneNumber: '1234 578 988',
            ClientName: 'ABX'
        };
        $('#lines').tmpl(line).appendTo('#window');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>

<div id="window">
    <script id="lines" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        
        Please contact us at ${PhoneNumber} and our client is ${ClientName}
    </script>
</div>
```

You may use jquery.tmpl to archive a template rendering.